# Will location data be available to ubuntu mobile apps?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is Ubuntu planning to make location data available to mobile applications? If so, can you give any pointers to an API that I could use?

Answer (score 4):

Though the Ubuntu SDK is based on  Qt5 and QtQuick 2.0, I think you are able to include [Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsensors-index.html). So the example [at this page](http://mirror.thecust.net/meego_1.2_harmattan_developer_documentation/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Developing_for_Harmattan_Using_location_and_maps_in_applications_Example_of_displaying_location_data_and_a_map_in_your_application.html) showing how to display location data on a map should work.

Comment: Both links seem to be dead.

Comment: Updated the links.